# Solution to reuse containers to expose LWC to tabs for Classic app

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-container

I am considering to build a Classic app which should consist of 5 to 10 tabs, each one containing single LWC component (single different LWC component).

I want to avoid code duplication and don't want to create multiple containers.

I would like to use as few reusable containers as possible.

I am looking for the most efficient solution in terms the least amount of containers possible in the current Spring '19 Release.

So far I was considering the following approach (which doesn't work completely)

I could create a standalone Lightning App `LWCContainer.app` with the following code

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="cmpName" type="String" default="lightning:button"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    Dynamic content here: <br/><br/>
    {!v.body} 
</aura:application>
```

and the controller

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        $A.createComponent(
            cmp.get("v.cmpName"),
            {
            },
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){

                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
            }
        );
    }
})
```

and then I could create a Web Tab with link `/c/LWCContainer.app?cmpName=c:fls` and a Web Tab with link `/c/LWCContainer.app?cmpName=c:ols` so that I would need  `n` or `O(n)` of Web Tabs and `1` or `O(1)` of custom Lightning App containers, whene `n` is the number of Tabs or LWC components I would like to expose as tabs.

However, this approach actually doesn't work due to inability of containing Lightning standalone apps or other Lightning components inside of iframes which is generating error

> Refused to display
>   'https://flsman-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/LWCContainer.app?cmpName=c:fls'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

[image]

---

Update: source code for two LWC components mentioned above.

lwc/fls/fls.html

```
<template>
    FLS!
    <br/>
    FLS 
</template>
```

lwc/fls/fls.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Fls extends LightningElement {}
```

lwc/fls/fls.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="fls">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

lwc/ols/ols.html

```
<template>
    OLS!
</template>
```

lwc/ols/ols.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Ols extends LightningElement {}
```

lwc/ols/ols.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="fls">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I think you are referring Lighting Aura Components and not Lightning Web Components (LWC), correct? LWC as of now is not supposed in Lightning Out. If that's the correct understanding, you may like to edit your post.

Comment: @JayantDas, no I actually refer to Lightning Web Components. I use Lightning Out Container as a middle layer between the tab and the Lightning Web Components.

Comment: Okay, because I didn't see an example as how LWC is tied to your Aura component, so was confused. You may probably like to add a LWC as an example in your question/answer to make it more clear?

Comment: I have updated my question to display the code for LWC components. However, they are irrelevant mostly here, their code is just dummy placeholder, the first component contains duplicated "FLS" string separated by horizontal break while the second component contains "OLS" string literal.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I asked to help someone like me who may get confused by thinking `c:fls` as an aura component! :)

Comment: No, `c:fls` cannot be standard aura component, it should definitely be either custom Aura component or custom Lightning Web Component since it has prefix `c` which corresponds to unmanaged components from organization without namespace. In my specific case, 'c:fls' and 'c:ols' are custom Lightning Web Components which references I try to pass dynamically through cmp.get("v.cmpName") using dynamic component creation in Aura container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the following solution which would require `n` tabs and 1 Visualforce page with 1 Lightning Out Container app.

Web tabs will have relative URLS referring to different LWC components like 
`/apex/LWCCont?cmpName=c:fls` or `/apex/LWCCont?cmpName=c:ols`.

Visualforce page will have the following code

```
<apex:page controller="LWCContController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lwcOut",    // name of the Lightning app
            function() {                  // Callback once framework and app loaded
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "{!cmpName}", // top-level component of your app
                    { },                  // attributes to set on the component when created
                    "lightning",   // the DOM location to insert the component
                    function(cmp) {
                        // callback when component is created and active on the page
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

with Apex Controller

```
public inherited sharing class LWCContController {

    public String cmpName { get{
        return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cmpName');
    } set; }
}
```

Also `lwcOut.app` will contain code of dummy lightning-out app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
</aura:application>
```

In total, this approach would need 3 custom container-related component to serve any number of LWC components to be exposed ( 1 Apex Class, 1 Visualforce Page, 1 Lightning Out Standalone App).

One drawback of this approach that on switching tab currently selected tab is not marked as selected which is disappointing. However, I don't know how to fix that.

[image]

[image]

If someone finds more elegant or sophisticated solution please share.